# How can I find out which tag wikis I can edit?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

How can I find out which tag wikis I can edit without clicking through to see if there is an `edit tag wiki` link offered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to look at your badges page and see if you have a bronze tag badge. (which is a good enough approximation of "score of 100 or more").

As for tags where you are among the Top 20 answerers, I have no idea (other than looking at a tag's [topusers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers))

Comment: Where do I find my tag badges? I added the *bash* wiki on SU but I can't see a Bash badge. Link to me on SU http://superuser.com/users/2013/nifle

Comment: @Nifle: You can find you tag badges by (1) hitting the "Badge" button and selecting the "tags" tab or (2) going to you profile, scrolling to the bottom and inspecting the tags that are shown there. But you can also edit wikis if you are among the top 20 answerers in a tag (regardless of the vote requirement), and as Null says there is no easy way to learn that: you have to go to the leader board for each tag and look.