# How can I see what tag wikis I am eligible to edit?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out which tag wikis I can edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66351/how-can-i-find-out-which-tag-wikis-i-can-edit)

Is there a way to get a list of the tag wikis that I am eligible to edit?

For bonus points, can I also see which of those don't already have a wiki entry?

Answer (score 1):

Even with our cache getting the list is going to be very tricky due to the rules.

The easy ones are all the tags you have bronze badges in. But for the ones you are in the top 20 its tricky, the query to find that is too expensive to show on the user page.

This could be authored on odata.stackexchange.com ... but its a very nasty query.

Comment: Well, a variation of this problem is getting a list of tags ordered by the score I have in that tag.  Is that possible / any easier?

Comment: @Kragen, yeah that one is easy http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/89/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag

Comment: Sweet - in that case I just need to work out what the threshold score is (the score of the 20th user) for each tag and compare my score - job done! :-)