# Can't help create new tag wiki

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki, privileges

I just gained the "Edit Tag Wikis" privilege and went to edit the `z-index` tag.  It "has no wiki" and I would like to help create it, so I clicked the link.

I am a [top 20 answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/z-index/topusers) and I [have more than 1500 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385273/steve).  But, there's no place for me to create/edit any info.  What's going on?

Comment: Hi Steve, we're constantly evaluating the criteria for these tag wikis and may reduce them over time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You may have broken the level of 1500 EXP, but for that particular tag you have neither</strike>

- a bronze badge for calls to sharecropping duty
- a spot in the top 20 answerers of all time OF ALL TIME!

Since you fail on both counts, you can [rule yourself out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66351/how-can-i-find-out-which-tag-wikis-i-can-edit) of being able to edit the tag wiki at this stage.

The new edit suggestion system allows you to suggest edits or new wikis for any tag.

Comment: Ahh ok.  I saw my name in last position on the the "All Time" list, but it turns out that list is 21 people long :(  Sort of disappointing if you're #21.  Maybe something to change? Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @Steve Actually, the last person displayed is always the person viewing the list, to allow you to compare yourself to others, so you might not necessarily be #21.

Comment: @waiwai The last person displayed is the person viewing the list only if you're at 20th or lower, and eligible for any score (this latter point is more visible on the Last 30 Days metric). If you're in the normal ranking, you'll be listed at the appropriate position, and not double-featured.

Comment: .. edited ...